# SQllite Query with Lower and Special Characters

Tags: sqlite

I have a Sqllite query

```
SELECT * FROM m_table WHERE LOWER(fName) = LOWER('yui!"'':;/?')  AND account = '100'  ORDER BY fName  COLLATE NOCASE ASC  ;
```

Above returns 0 rows; But when I use the same as below , it Works

```
update m_table set fName = 'yui!"'':;/? renamed' where fname='yui!"'':;/?' AND account = '100';
```

Any clues ?

PS: I am using LOWER to ignore case sensitive. I am using this via an android client. Hence
I am also doing StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql("folderName")

Comment: Maybe because you're making query on `foldername` and update on `fname`?

Comment: Edit : folderName/fName are same :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the fact, that your input string contains characters in a non-ASCII-charset. from the documentation of SQLlite:

> lower(X) -- The lower(X) function returns a copy of string X with all
>   ASCII characters converted to lower case. The default built-in lower()
>   function works for ASCII characters only. To do case conversions on
>   non-ASCII characters, load the ICU extension.
>   http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Try to run the following statement and see what it returns.

```
SELECT LOWER(fName) FROM m_table WHERE fname='yui!"'':;/?' AND account = '100';
```